# Corda OS v4.3 throws exception when run in DEBUG mode java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64 in java.library.path

Tags: corda

I am running corda OS v4.3 in debug mode and observed following exception

```
    [DEBUG] 2020-01-16T12:11:16,058Z [main] internal.NativeLibraryLoader. - netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64 cannot be loaded from java.libary.path, now trying export to -Dio.netty.native.workdir: /tmp
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:243) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:124) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:183) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.22.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:61) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.22.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:33) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.22.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor.start(NettyAcceptor.java:341) ~[artemis-server-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl.startAcceptors(RemotingServiceImpl.java:302) ~[artemis-server-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.completeActivation(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2464) ~[artemis-server-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run(LiveOnlyActivation.java:74) ~[artemis-server-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:535) ~[artemis-server-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:474) ~[artemis-server-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.ArtemisMessagingServer.configureAndStartServer(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:104) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.messaging.ArtemisMessagingServer.start(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:73) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.startMessagingService(Node.kt:286) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:380) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:447) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:210) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupCli$runProgram$2.run(NodeStartup.kt:131) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup$initialiseAndRun$5.invoke(NodeStartup.kt:187) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup$initialiseAndRun$5.invoke(NodeStartup.kt:138) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupLogging$DefaultImpls.attempt(NodeStartup.kt:529) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.attempt(NodeStartup.kt:138) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.initialiseAndRun(NodeStartup.kt:186) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupCli.runProgram(NodeStartup.kt:129) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapper.call(CordaCliWrapper.kt:190) ~[corda-tools-cliutils-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupCli.call(NodeStartup.kt:84) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupCli.call(NodeStartup.kt:65) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1173) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$800(CommandLine.java:141) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:1367) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:1335) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.handleParseResult(CommandLine.java:1243) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at picocli.CommandLine.parseWithHandlers(CommandLine.java:1526) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapperKt.start(CordaCliWrapper.kt:73) ~[corda-tools-cliutils-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
```

I believe this exception can be ignored as it doesn't affect the normal functioning.
I noticed this for Oracle JDK(1.8.0_212) as well as openJDK-8.
What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that netty (web framework that Corda uses: https://netty.io/) logs the stack trace if netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64 is not found in the java path. In this case, it seems like it's not necessarily an error and is out of the control of Corda.

See this issue on netty: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7319